# onclick of input /textarea field getting [object Object]

Tags: reactjs

on focus of input/textarea field i am getting input value as following [object Object] . i am not getting why its happening and i am setting state to value of input field . but while on-focus the input field i am getting only [object object].  its not become able to type anything also 
My snippet is here

```
<textarea rows='5'
                cols='auto'
                onFocus={this.onFocus.bind(this, 'Assessment', isRecording)}
                value={this.value}
                onChange={this.onTextChangedUsingKeyboard.bind(this)}
                onSelect={this.onEditSelectionChange.bind(this)}
                />

onFocus(sectionName, isRecording) {
    this.props.changeSection(sectionName, isRecording);
  }

  onTextChangedUsingKeyboard(text) {
    this.props.onTextChangedUsingKeyboard(text);
  }

  onEditSelectionChange(event) {

  }
```

Comment: There is no onClick method provided. Where do you check your onClick event?

Comment: onfous is there know

Comment: @Ramusesan please include your `onFocus` function.

Comment: @james u mean onfocus code

Comment: @Ramusesan yes.

Comment: onFocus(sectionName, isRecording) {
    this.props.changeSection(sectionName, isRecording);
  }

  onTextChangedUsingKeyboard(text) {
    this.props.onTextChangedUsingKeyboard(text);
  }

  onEditSelectionChange(event) {
    this.props.handleEditCursorPosition(event.nativeEvent.selection.start, event.nativeEvent.selection.end);
  }

Comment: I'd say the problem is with `onTextChangedUsingKeyboard` handler. It set passes full event object to `this.props.onTextChangedUsingKeyboard`. Make sure it actually extracts value `text.target.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a mistake in method:

```
onTextChangedUsingKeyboard(text) {
    this.props.onTextChangedUsingKeyboard(text);
}
```

Because you trigger it in `onChange` event, and `text` param in method is not a `String` text, it's an Event Object. That should be better:

```
onTextChangedUsingKeyboard(event) {
    this.props.onTextChangedUsingKeyboard(event.target.value);
}
```